# Jackson fails to serialize a null Double

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to serialize an object into an array and Jackson fails to do so with NPE.

I am expecting something like [1, null, 10] in the response, but do not understand why Jackson throws NPE instead of serializing a null value.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public static class PointTO {
    private long x;
    private Double y;
    private int volume;

    public PointTO(long x, Double y, int volume) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public long getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public Double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: de.bnext.web.model.DisplayOrderBookResponseTO["curves"]-&gt;java.util.ArrayList[0]-&gt;de.bnext.web.model.CurveTO["points"]-&gt;java.util.ArrayList[15]-&gt;de.bnext.web.model.PointTO["y"])
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:197)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:183)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.BeanAsArraySerializer.serializeAsArray(BeanAsArraySerializer.java:192)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.BeanAsArraySerializer.serialize(BeanAsArraySerializer.java:147)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:94)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:180)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:544)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:94)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:180)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:544)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:120)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1728)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:194)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Comment: I am not trying to deserialize. I am serializing a java object into JSON using Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. Can you report this at:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues

along with information like which Jackson version you are using?

As error message indicates, it looks as if property "y" handling fails: I am guessing it is because it is a wrapper object and some part of code assumes it can be auto-unboxed into `double` value. So a check needs to be added in appropriate place.

Comment: I think the 'wrap' parts in the stacktrace come from exception handling (wrapping).

Comment: Yes, quite probably. Still, a bug report would be helpful, since this is for somewhat specialized code path -- serializing a POJO as JSON Array. So it could be some simple oversight. Or, since it's been a while, also possible newer versions might have resolved the issue.

Comment: I thought I am facing the same problem, but it turned out to be a bug in my POJO causing NPE. Since we don't know which Jackson version @afansky has been using it's difficult to find out if the problem exists. In case it was Jackson 1.4, this could have been the problem http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-222.